# Is "fPrince" a real word?

Tags: typographical-errors

I saw this on the [NYT web site](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/09/opinion/prince-philip-dead.html?action=click&module=Well&pgtype=Homepage&section=Contributors) today (4/9/2021):

[image]

**Is "fPrince" a real word, or is it an incredible typo??**

Comment: Do you have a subscription? I do and mine does not have the typo: https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/09/opinion/prince-philip-dead.html?action=click&module=Opinion&pgtype=Homepage

Comment: Looks like a French site made an HTML mistake. The French site is: https://www.voici.fr/sitemap_article_2011-0.xml They took the NYT article and made a typo in their formatting? The actual NYT article did not have this AM or afternoon.

Comment: Could it be related to Will Smith's [The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fresh_Prince_of_Bel-Air)? I think His Highness might have been amused by that idea.

Comment: OK, they appear to have edited the page.  I guess it was simply a typo.  A bit sloppy for the NYT.

Comment: Probably some formatting character that was erroneously left in.  Agreeing with @Lambie .

Comment: @Lambie - My link was to the page that I got through my subscription to NYT.  Unclear how it could somehow have gotten fouled up due to French formatting.  (The error also appeared on the "front page" that linked to the article.)

Comment: If "fPrince" were a real word, I'd want to write a song called "The fPrince of Pflugerville" just so I could hear how the singer pronounced it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the online article has subsequently been edited to change "fPrince" to "Prince", it appears that it was a simple typo.

Uncharacteristic for the New York Times, but I suppose the article may have been posted in a hurry.

Comment: It's not like they could not have seen this coming.